# Computer shuts down after waking from sleep mode

Tags: suspend

I wake up the computer (desktop PC, not laptop) by pressing a key, the login screen appears. The moment I want to enter the password, the computer shuts down. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

More info needed. After reboot finished, check:
dmesg -T  --level=err,warn
Post output here.

Also post output of:
cat /proc/swaps

Comment: So several things to look into. 1G swap is not much when suspended to disk. This might be the cause. See for info:
https://itsfoss.com/swap-size/    


Also worth to check bios/efi if suspend to ram option is present and enabled. Final note is on suspend/ hiberate behaviour.
You can try to tingle with settings of: /etc/systemd/sleep.conf.  


arch wiki can inform further:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management#Hybrid-sleep_on_suspend_or_hibernation_request

Comment: Hello @odin. Thanks for your tips and efforts. I have increased the swap memory by 10 GB to 11 GB (my RAM is 8 GB). The problem does not appear again so far :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hello @odin thank you for the answer. Here are the outputs:

> cat /proc/swaps

**Filename** /dev/dm-1 **Type** partition **Size** 999420 **Used** 0 **Priority** -2

> dmesg -T --level=err,warn

[link](https://share.anoxinon.de/f.php?h=3Uur4TS_beLbGnBfhyosii)